# Change the color of the "tick" in the WordPress login page

Tags: wordpress-theming

I was not able to change the color of the "[tick](https://i.stack.imgur.com/woSbI.png)" symbol located inside the checkbox of the WordPress login page to a different color.

I've ended up finding that it was an "svg" file and was placed somewhere inside the WordPress folder. I've searched long trying to find the path inorder to replace it with a new file which contains the desired color but to no vail.

Can anyone help and I'll be grateful :)